# sslCommerz SDK conflict with Swift version

Tags: swift, swiftui, sdk, preview

It's a Uikit project, have sslCommerz sdk(written in obj-C). And now initiate SwiftUI, but it shows an error given below, when preview appears. [image: Error]

how to solve this issue?

Didn't try anything to solve. But app runs and specific SwiftUI view appears correctly.